# Better Apache index of files?

Tags: apache-2.2, css

I'm looking for a better looking of apache "index of file", I have tried one get the effect from this,
http://imm.io/media/3m/3m1f.png

to this,

[image]

But is there any other better looing for apache "index of file", could you recommend some better?

I think the looking of firefox directory indexing is better,

[image]
Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Apache's [mod_autoindex](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_autoindex.html) provides you lots of flexibility. With it you can add to your directory listings a header section, customize the looks with CSS, modify the icons and whatnot.

If that is not enough for you, it's possible to pass a dynamic script as your **DirectoryIndex** file - for example `DirectoryIndex /webroot/shared/my_custom_dir.php` would call a PHP script from path `/webroot/shared/my_custom_dir.php` for generating the directory listing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "FancyIndexing" and "FoldersFirst" directives in Apache configuration